# Como hacer que mediante un icono suba para arriba

Tags: javascript, html, css

Buenas tengo un sistema que tiene un icono para ir para arriba, como podría hacer que eso suceda intente con un ejemplo de que es siguiente pero no me resulto, como lo podría hacer con un icono imagen referencial: https://ibb.co/gtrLTZT

```js
<script>
    let btn = document.querySelector("button")

    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
    })
  </script>
```

```css
<style>
        html {
          scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }
      </style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <style>
        html {
          scroll-behavior: smooth;
        }
      </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</div>
      <button>Ir arriba</button>
    <script>
  
    </script>
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Espero le pueda ayudar a alguien: <li><a href="#" id="irarriba">Ir arriba</a></li> <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#irarriba').click(function(){ //Id del elemento cliqueable
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 1250);
   return false;
  });
 });
</script>

Comment: Coloca el código que te funcionó como respuesta y no como comentario. Despues acepta tu propia pregunta para evitar confusiones

Answer (score 1):

Si en vez de un `botton` pones un enlace `a` con href='#' (el # va hacia el principio de la página) será suficiente, ni siquiera tendrás que usar javascript

```css
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
p {
    padding: 30px;
}
a {
    padding: 20px;
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores quod eius, nemo recusandae soluta veniam quas dolorem, error, molestiae explicabo culpa voluptatem ipsa quos tempora unde? Saepe magnam aut corporis!</p>
      
      
      <a href='#'>Ir arriba</a>
```